# Open Source CMS in PHP with Security facts!

Tags: php, security, drupal, joomla

I have a experience on Joomla, Drupal, wordpress and small cms configuration. But one of my client is asking about the security level in the above cms. I never thought about the security risks and it's really very new to me. On which basis i can choose which is best CMS when considering about the security level and minimum risks? And what kind of security we can provide to the server make the application highly secured?

Comment: Just check security advisories like [Secunia](http://secunia.com/advisories/search/) for security issues. Security will most probably by affected by 3rd party modules you install, so you should audit these for any issues before implementing them. And once you select a specific CMS, subscribe to their security related mailing list (if they have one anyway).

Comment: yes. You are right. 3rd party modules may put in to risk.

Comment: As wimvds mentioned, it's not so much the CMS that is the problem (most of the time) it's the extensions. Joomla is pretty good at keeping this list up to date - http://docs.joomla.org/Vulnerable_Extensions_List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the big CMS products you mentioned should be okay. Look at who else is using them; this is a great way to judge how good the product really is. For example, Drupal is used by the White House. This fact gives me a lot of confidence in Drupal.

The important thing is to make certain that you keep up-to-date with any security fixes that are released.

The vast majority of security problems in all these products come from non-core modules that you might install. If you're really worried about security, I suggest keeping the number of modules you use to an absolute minimum.

Where you do need to use an external module, do thorough investigations to find out how good it is: how often is it updated? are there any known bugs with it which may be security issues? how widely used is it? And as I mentioned above with the core CMS, who is using it?

You should also ensure that your web server is secure. It's not just your CMS that will provide routes in for a hacker. Close all un-necessary ports and services. Make sure that everything possible is encrypted (use SFTP, definitely not FTP). If you're using a PHP-based CMS such as Drupal, use a security-hardened PHP version ([Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/)) rather than the basic version.

Finally, you should accept that no matter how good your software and no matter how vigilant you are, you could still get hacked. Worse, you could get hacked without even knowing about it. Even the best software has flaws which can be exploited. For this reason, you should aim to have several layers of security before anyone can get to any genuinely sensitive data.

Comment: The other thing to mention is configuration. Drupal is good out of the box, but, once you have set up your admin accounts and their rights and fiddled around with who can see what, there's no guarantee it's still fine.